# A slash is being automatically added after the hashtag in urls

Tags: articles, templates, url

I just wanted to implement a scroll to an element for two anchor tags. The problem is that Joomla is adding a forward slash between the hash mark and the named anchor.

When I have something like `<a href="#abc">ABC</a>`,
the URL that Joomla produces is `www.example.com/#/abc`.

Does anyone know how to stop the `#` from becoming a directory?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on a Joomla 3.9 installation. Suggest looking at your .htaccess versus the stock version: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/htaccess.txt. If they are the same, look at what plugins you have enabled and temporarily disable them.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Matthias.  Please take our [tour].  What template are you using?  Here is a scenario where urls were getting mutated by a GavickPro template: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=974470